# How do I pass parameters to events?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Some of my variables are not getting serialized each method invocation.

How do I know where arguments go?

```
public static int button21_Click(object me, EventArgs MyArgs) {
  button17(me, MyArts);
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you even *try* reinstalling .Net as a solution?

Comment: i am sorry my english is not very readable

Comment: @Pharsh: try asking 1 thing at a time, and ask it better.

Comment: @Henk Holterman 1 min ago i am sorry

Comment: Do you have a method button17(object me, EventArgs MyArgs) in your code. My guess is you are trying to call button 17 clickable method. So try button17_Click(me, MyArts); instead of button17(me...

Comment: how the change made to my question? i am sorry, again, since i can get answer could someone new ask

Comment: I suggest that this question remain closed until Prashant clarifies it. He opened [Please help me to ask my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76802) on Meta: if he wants to he can work with people there to improve/explain the question.

Answer (score 8):

I admit that I am not entirely certain what you are asking, but from what I can see, you appear to be trying to use the same event handler for multiple `Button.Click` events. You can do this in two ways.

#### 1. Using the WinForms designer.

Select one of your buttons then hit F4 or go to the Properties window and select the Events tab (it's the one with the icon that looks like a lightning bolt). Then find the Click event and create a new handler. Then go to each of the other buttons and find their Click event and just use the dropdown to select the handler you already created.

#### 2. Using code.

In code, create an event handler, then add that event handler to each button's `Click` event.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Do stuff to handle the event.
}

// This is the form's constructor.
public MyWinForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.button1.Click += OnClick;
    this.button2.Click += OnClick;
    this.button3.Click += OnClick;
    this.button4.Click += OnClick;
    this.button5.Click += OnClick;
    this.button6.Click += OnClick;
    this.button7.Click += OnClick;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make a reasonable answer and it dived aswell.. suggest you just delete it like I did...

Comment: @Moo-Juice 53 mins ago i saw your answer and i thank you

Comment: @PRASHANT P, there undeleted :P

Answer (score 2):

I was about to just write some kind of canned-response that firstly pointed out that I voted to close the question, and secondly made some derogatory remark about your English and the fact that one has to be a mind-reader to even *get* what you're talking about.  Then I thought to hell with it, let's have a shot.

I'll ignore the fact that, in your code, `button17(me, MyArts);` makes no sense at all.  I assume you want to raise an event on it, or pass the arguments on, to another button.  Firstly you've put `MyArts` instead of `MyArgs`, so there's a compilation error right here.  Secondly, `button17` is likely already constructed and doesn't need constructing again.  I suspect your actual motive is to call some other method on it, passing the arguments on.

Thirdly, this method is static.  So if it is a member of a class, it has no access to any member-variables of it, so when it does get called, `this` is not valid and you're in the global namespace without a paddle.  Consider making it non-static.

Hope this helps.  I know bikers that wouldn't try and answer this.

Comment: [Other people's] downvotes might have been for being snide, but [my] +1 for also trying to answer helpfully.

Comment: Snide snarkiness is why I don't visit this otherwise incredibly valuable website much anymore. :(