# How do I pass extra arguments to my event handlers?

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to call a shared global event handler from my form's button click event.

```
public void button21_Click(object me, EventArgs MyArgs) {
  button17_Click(me, MyArgs);  /// WORKS!
}
```

What I want to do is pass in my XML to the method.

Something like:

```
public void button21_Click(object me, EventArgs MyArgs) {
  button17_Click(me, MyArgs, MyXmlString);  /// ERROR!
}
```

I do not always need XML in the button17_Click() method, only when button21 is pressed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your friend is certainly fluent in "internet english". But this is just a duplicate of your previous question. Have you really made no progress since yesterday?

Comment: How can a button be depressed?

Comment: @AS-CII Sad button is never clicked. http://www.mp3-to-m4r.net/images/sad-button.png

Comment: @bzlm i got told on metastackoverflow to ask my question with better wording so i am doing this so it must be duplicate but better

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass parameters to events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822307/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-events)

Comment: @AS-CII my cousin writes manuals and has tells me "depressed" is what is happens when you have been gone down on buttons!

Comment: @ALL THANK YOU FOR BEING THE HELP many good answers!!

Comment: @Prash: It's more common to say a button is/was Pressed. A depressed person is very sad. The commenters here were playing some word-jokes on you, a little unfair.

Comment: and what is number -2 * 1 by question

Comment: @me i understand the rep i am sorry never mind my question i will increase

Comment: OK, this question is a little better than yesterday, bu we still can't see :

 - what is the declaration of button17_Click
 - why is button17_Click an eventhandler?
 - why is it a 'global' eventhandler ?
 - what do you mean by 'global' here?
 - is it your code (can you change button17_Click) ?
 - ...


And all that is needed to form an answer or an advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not try to call your event handler directly, leave that up to the events themselves.

What you should do instead is move the logic for `button17` into a separate method and call that method instead.

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the newly created method instead (with the XML argument null)
    HandleClickOperation(null);
}

private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the newly created method instead (with the XML argument set)
    HandleClickOperation(MyXmlString);
}

private void HandleClickOperation(string xmlString)
{
    if (xmlString == null)
    {
        // do things unique to button17 behavior
    }
    else
    {
        // do things unique to button21 behavior
    }
    // the logic that was in button17_Click()
}
```

Comment: my friend told me something like this but with button17_Click_Aux instead of HadleClickOperation!

Comment: @PRASHANT: You're free to name it whatever you want.  I just didn't know what your code actually did so I gave it a generic name.  The key is that you don't use the method as an event handler directly.

Comment: @Jeff M i understand the names i think this is the abstarction

Comment: @Jeff M my remaining only question is why events are not pubic

Comment: @PRASHANT: Normally when you create event handlers for an event, it is declared a private instance method and I stuck with that.  In your case, you declared them public.  That's fine too.  Just make sure to adjust the code to fit your needs.  You don't have to use our examples exactly as written.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass XML (or other arbitrary data types) to event handlers in .NET. They have a particular signature, and that's what you have to use.

You should not be calling button17_click from button21_click. Instead, try this:

```
public void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonFunctionality();
}

public void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonFunctionality();
}

private void CommonFunctionality()
{
    // In here, place the code that used to be in button17_click
}
```

You may then need to create a version of the common functionality that can use your XML.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this question is a little better than yesterday, bu we still can't see :

- what is the declaration of button17_Click
- why is button17_Click an eventhandler?
- why is it a 'global' eventhandler ?
- what do you mean by 'global' here?
- is it your code (can you change button17_Click) ?
- ...

And all that is needed to form an answer or an advice.

Comment: he's up to `button21_Click` by now ;-)